# Webi - Ranking Sections displays wrong order

Tags: business-objects

I have a list of customers and their revenue. For certain reasons, I want to display one section per customer, for the TOP 10 customers (in regards to their revenues). Sounds simple.

However, when I activate the ranking for the sections, the customer with the 7th highest revenue is placed on the top of the list, and is given the running count '8'.

[image: one section per customer, wrong order]

I tried everything I could think of to put them back into order, with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution - the reason for this strange behaviour is the fact that section filters don't always seem to work.

Let me explain:

I had a filter on both the section and the table therein, limiting customers only to a certain subgroup thereof. The filter on the table worked, so that the displayed revenue represented the correct revenue I expected. However, the filter on the section did NOT work, so that the ranking took into consideration the entire revenue, and not only the subgroup's revenue. Therefore Customer 8 landed on first place, because in total, he had the highest revenue.

So if you have this problem, check your filters.

Next, I'll be trying to find out why the section filters don't apply...